# Orber By syntax issue in PHP/Ajax script

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have the following code snippet that is working find but am trying to sort the results ASC.  I've tried numerous variations and none work?

```
$res = mysql_query('SELECT DISTINCT call FROM ' . DB_TABLE);
```

Does not work:

```
$res = mysql_query('SELECT DISTINCT call FROM ' . DB_TABLE . 'ORDER BY call ASC');
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

Comment: @RoccoTheTaco that shouldn't make any difference, does `mysql_error` return anything for the query with ORDER BY ?

Comment: Embarrassed to say I was missing a space before ORDER ...devil is in the details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss a space :

```
$res = mysql_query('SELECT DISTINCT call FROM ' . DB_TABLE . ' ORDER BY call ASC');
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
$res = mysql_query('SELECT DISTINCT call FROM ' . DB_TABLE . ' ORDER BY call ASC');
```

Note the space before ORDER

Answer (score 0):

Try using the backtick (`) operator with your mysql query.

```
$res = mysql_query('SELECT DISTINCT `call` FROM ' . DB_TABLE . ' ORDER BY `call` ASC');
```

And all should work well.